# Manually update custom currency exchange rate

Tags: custom, currency, currency-rates

I have created a custom exchange rate, and I am attempting to find a way to change the exchange rate.

I clicked "update" on the Manage Currency Rates admin page, but I cannot modify the number at all.

What should I do to change the rate and ensure that any sort of auto update (cron?) does not impact the number?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of your currency setup page? I have no problem changing the rates here: `System > Manage Currencies > Rates`

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Although I can click inside the box, I cannot add any values.  - http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/5580/dmil.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add more currencies under `System > Config > GENERAL > Currency Setup > Currency Options` then you can change the rate between them.

You can **NOT** change the rate between ABC and ABC ;-)

Comment: Is there anyway I can compare the rate to USD but display ABC in both Admin and Frontend?  I need to set the rate because I'm pulling products from amazon (so I want the price multiplied by 133) but in admin it's showing everything as $100 and in frontend, ABC 13300